# Can a Beastmaster Ranger riding his Animal Companion take the Dash action every turn in addition to his action?

Tags: dnd-5e

In the PHB (p 198) there are rules given for mounts:

> While you're mounted, you have two options. You can either control
>   the mount or allow it to act independently. Intelligent creatures,
>   such as dragons, act independently.
>
> You can control a mount only if it
>   has been trained to accept a rider. Domesticated horses, donkeys, and
>   similar creatures are assumed to have such training. The initiative o
>   f a controlled mount changes to match yours when you mount it. It
>   moves as you direct it, and **it has only three action options: Dash,
>   Disengage, and Dodge.** A controlled mount can move and act even on the
>   turn that you mount it.

However, the rules for animal companions (PHB93) state:

> The beast obeys your commands as best as it can. It takes its turn on
>   your initiative, though **it doesn’t take an action unless you command
>   it to.** On your turn, you can verbally command the beast where to move
>   (no action required by you). **You can use your action to verbally
>   command it to take the Attack, Dash, Disengage, Dodge, or Help action.**

Nothing in the mount rules say that a mount can take an action when it would be unable to without a rider - only that its actions are restricted to those three.

Can the mount dash, disengage, or dodge while the rider also takes an action?